# Run-time error '424' Object required

Tags: vba, excel, exception, runtime-error

Writing a Macro to run a loop which runs a VLOOKUP across each cell in an column. I'm getting a "Run-time error '424' Object required" error but can't pin down the main issue. Any insight or help is appreciated.

Two Issues:
* Run-time error '424' Object required
* Loop continues past last cell with Data until wrap-around or Excel Limit is hit before stopping. Using the dot operators for .ActiveCell and .Value aren't helping.
[image]

```
Sub New_contact_info()

serverName = Cells.Range("AS:AS")
contactInfo = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(serverName, Worksheets("All Active Assets").Range("A:C"), 3, False)

Cells.Range("AM:AM") = contactInfo

For Each cell In serverName
If serverName <> "" Then
serverName.ValueOffset(0, -5) = contactInfo
End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that it sould not be like this: "If cell<> "" Then

Comment: That line is now clear, the next line is throwing the same error, I've now tried "cell.Offset(0, 5) = contactInfo" to no avail

Comment: Just an advice - Write "Option Explicit" on the top of your code and then  do "Debug">"Compile" from the top menu. It would show you all compile errors. See here for "Option Explicit" -> http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the range serverName using the "Set" keyword.
Give this a try:

```
Sub New_contact_info()
  dim serverName as Range

  set serverName = Cells.Range("AS:AS")
  contactInfo = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(serverName,  Worksheets("All Active Assets").Range("A:C"), 3, False)

  Cells.Range("AM:AM").value = contactInfo

  For Each cell In serverName
    If serverName.value <> "" Then
      serverName.Value.Offset(0, -5) = contactInfo
    End If

  Next cell

End Sub
```